# Time frames (aka Sprints) field are out of order in Power BI visuals

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

[image: Problem]

[image: Table]

I'm having issues with these two time frames in my Power BI dashboard that are out of order. I'm wondering what I can do to fix this issue. I already sorted the timeframes to ascending and it didn't do the trick for me, unfortunately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's sorting alphabetically. To fix this, add a column in the query editor that is either just the start date or end date of the Time Frame (make sure the column is a date type) and then use the [sort by column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column) feature to sort your Time Frame column by the new date column you just created.

Note that this probably won't work if you add the column as a DAX calculated column (rather than in the query editor) because it will throw a circular logic error (since the calculated column is dependent on the Time Frame).